# In Angular, is there a way to import and use external libraries downloaded with npm within component scope?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to import and use https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-color-picker as the color picker as the default Angular color picker only allows rgb and does not intake the alpha value in the rgba.

Currently, I'm trying to use it within page that is at a component scope. I did do some research and it was suggested to be imported and used with @ngModule which is a module, but I am currently finding a method to import it within the component html page where @component is used as the project that I'm working on is not my own project and I have limitation changing the overall architecture of the project.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderNavigationItem } from 'src/app/shared/models/headerNavigationItem';
import { CacheService } from 'src/app/shared/services/cache.service';
import { CustomConfigDetailService } from 'src/app/shared/services/custom-config-detail.service';
import { HeaderNavigationTitleService } from 'src/app/shared/services/header-navigation-title.service';
import { LoaderService } from 'src/app/shared/services/loader.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { ColorPickerModule } from 'ngx-color-picker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-maps-colorline',
  templateUrl: './maps-colorline.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maps-colorline.component.css'],
})

// @NgModule({
//   imports: [ColorPickerModule],
// })
```

Any help or other method would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Not going to work. You need to import `ColorPickerModule` in the same or parent module where your `app-maps-colorline` Component is declared.

Comment: If the ColorPickerModule is imported in the parent module where everything is declared, can it be used inside the maps-colorline.component.html?

Comment: That is correct.